# Permission denied viewing content of remote network share

Tags: mount, 13.04, permissions, fstab, remote

I'm trying to mount a remote network share, but have trouble viewing the content.
It is showing up in my mounted devices but when I attempt to open it, I get

*This location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “liffey”.*

My fstab entry looks like this:

```
//liffey.cis.utas.edu.au\lukass /media/utas/liffey cifs sec=ntlmv2,credentials=/root/.utascredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0711,dir_mode=0711, 0 0
```

When liffey is mounted the permissions look like this:

```
drwx------ 22 10455   204    0 Mar 14 14:09 liffey
```

but unmounted:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 lukas lukas 4096 May  6 16:44 liffey
```

my *.utascredential* file:

```
-rwx--x--x  1 lukas root   34 May  4 20:56 .utascredentials
```

I can have rw access as root, so it must be a local permission conflict.

I'm stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dir_mode is 711. It's rwxr--r--. Directories need to be executable. Try changing it to 755.

And set your .utascredential file to: -rwxr-xr-x